# Service to service Name does not resolve ECS Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, aws-fargate

I tried to deploy the following project to AWS Fargate by docker compose CLI.

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3"
x-aws-vpc: vpc-04db4c9a69a101123

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine
    container_name: redis
    networks:
      - default

  nettool:
    image: praqma/network-multitool:latest
    container_name: nettool
    depends_on:
      - redis
    command: >
      /bin/bash -c "sleep 30 && ping redis"
    networks:
      - default

networks:
  default:
    external: true
    name: sg-076b1c7d0cfaac123
```

AWS Context as administrator permission. I deploy the project by `docker compose up`. It deploys with load balancer being used and required 2 subnet masks, I fulfilled it.

`ping redis` at nettool service got Name does not resolve

I hope here is somebody who can help me!